# changing the rotation of one dataset from my chartjs pie-chart

Tags: charts, rotation, dataset, chart.js, pie-chart

Is have a chartjs pie-chart with 2 datasets.
Is it possible to change the rotation of just one dataset, so that the 2 datasets have different rotations?

Comment: Hi @Marco, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No, did not find one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65309224/how-to-rotate-datalabels-in-charts-js-with-plugins