# How to rotate datalabels in Charts.js with plugins?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to plot the wind speed in a canvas graph using Charts.js. The data (wind speed and wind direction) comes from a JSON URL. Everything works fine with the code and the plot looks like this:

[image]

I was able to add the arrows by using the Plugins from Charts.js, a `formatter` and a `rotation` function, but what I would like to do is to have the arrows rotated according to the wind direction angle that comes from the JSON.

The JSON file has a format that looks like this:

[image]

So far, a part of the code looks like this:

```js
Current = Date.now();
$.getJSON("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat={LAT}&lon={LONG}&dt=" + Current + "&appid={MY API CODE}", function(data) {
      $.each(data.hourly, function(key, value) {
        var d = new Date(value.dt * 1000);
        minutes = "0" + d.getMinutes()
        var date_corrected = d.getFullYear() + "-" + [d.getMonth() + 1] + '-' + d.getDate() + ' ' + [d.getHours()] + ':' + minutes.substr(-2);
        dataOpen1.push({
          x: date_corrected,
          y: value.wind_speed
        });
        dataOpen2.push({
          x: date_corrected,
          y: value.wind_deg
        });

      });
      var WIND = new Chart(vant, {
          plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
          type: 'line',
          data: {
            labels: dataOpen1.map(x => x.x),
            datasets: [{
              data: dataOpen1.map(y => y.y),
              label: 'Viteza vantului ',
              borderColor: "#3e95cd",
              fill: true
            }, ]
          },
          options: {
            plugins: {
              datalabels: {
                backgroundColor: 'white',
                borderRadius: 20,
                borderWidth: 3,
                borderDashOffset: 20,
                color: 'black',
                font: {
                  size: 18
                },
                formatter: function(value) {
                  return '\u27a3'
                },
                rotation: function(ctx) {
                  return ctx.dataset.data[ctx.dataIndex] * 25;
                },
                padding: 0
              }
            },
          });
      });
```

So I would like to get the values from `dataOpen2` (with the wind direction) and use it to set the rotation angle of the arrows per each data set. I know that the code has to be here:

```js
rotation:
  function(ctx) {
.......
    return ctx.dataset.data[ctx.dataIndex] * 25;
  },
```

But I don't really have any idea how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Issue at github repository for CHARTJS https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5667

You may need to adjust your data in following way:

```
dataOpen1.push({
          x: date_corrected,
          y: value.wind_speed
          d: value.wind_deg
});
```

And then you can modify using datalable plugin your function as

```
rotation: function(ctx) { return ctx.dataset.data[ctx.dataIndex].d; }
```